# Fortify BirtReportGenerator Search

Tags: fortify

I'm running the Fortify BIRT Report Generator from the command line, and trying to limit the generated report to only "critical" and "high" issues. The actual command line is below.

```
birtreportgenerator -template "Developer Workbook" -format PDF 
    -output "output.pdf" -source "input.fpr"
    -searchQuery "[fortify priority order]:critical OR [fortify priority order]:high"
```

But I'm getting the following Exception:

```
Error parsing search string, Unknown Modifier: fortify priority order
com.fortify.exceptions.FortifyException: Error parsing search string, Unknown Modifier: fortify priority order
```

The Fortify SCA User Guide only says the option syntax is:

```
-searchQuery <query>
```

But it never bothers to specify what form `<query>` is supposed to take.

In the Audit Workbench's BIRT report generation function, I can specify a filter by going to *Issue Filter Settings > Filter > Advanced* and selecting priority orders of critical or high. When I do that, the filter field is populated with:

```
[fortify priority order]:critical OR [fortify priority order]:high
```

and the generated report is correctly limited to only critical and high defects.

So, why the query syntax that works in Audit Workbench's report generator fails in the command line report generator, I have no idea. The Fortify Audit Workbench User Guide specifically lists [fortify priority order] as a valid search modifier, for what that's worth.

I've tried every variation of the syntax I could think of, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: What version of SCA are you using (`sourceanalyzer -version`) and what OS?  I am using 16.11 on Windows 10 and your command worked like a charm.

Comment: HP Fortify Static Code Analyzer 6.40.0089 (using JVM 1.8.0_45) on Win 7